# No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system

Tags: java, ubuntu-16.04

I am running Ubuntu 16 on my computer and
I am attempting to run a Java application on my computer and I get the following error:

```
No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system.
The version of the JVM must be at least 11.
Please define INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to point to a suitable JVM.
```

However I have already Java installed and a virtual machine.
When I press

```
$java -version
```

I get the following output:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_192"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.33.0.1-linux64) (build 1.8.0_192-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.33.0.1-linux64) (build 25.192-b01, mixed mode)
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem? Many thanks.

Comment: Java application explicitly asks you about significant JVM's version, as you found you have 1.8 installed instead of 11. Just follow the instructions: update it or install another one and set it in `INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME ` env var.

Answer (score 5):

Compare

> The version of the JVM must be at least 11

and

> openjdk version "1.8.0_192"

(i.e. Java 8)

Upgrade your Java version.

Answer (score 4):

From the output above, it is evident that an updated version of Java is missing. You need at least a version of JVM equal to 11 or upper.

Let’s now proceed and install both JRE and JDK which both constitute JAVA

**JRE**

Ubuntu

```
sudo apt install default-jre
```

Arch

```
sudo pacman -S jre-openjdk
```

**JDK**

Ubuntu

```
sudo apt install default-jdk
```

Arch

```
sudo pacman -sS java | grep jdk
sudo pacman -S jdk-openjdk
```

you can check the version with [java -version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA6Q1.png)

```
java -version
```

Comment: under-rated answer because the majority of the time anyone gets this is because they are on a default setup without java installed yet. `INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME` not being set is telling because the installations will set that up by default. Thank you for answering this question with practical steps for people troubleshooting.